# Is there a way to assign a maximum number of clusters using DBSCAN?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, dbscan

If I am trying to cluster my data using DBSCAN, is there a way to assign a maximum number of clusters? I know I can set the minimum distance between points to be considered a cluster, but my data changes case by case and I would prefer to not allow more than 4 clusters. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with DBSCAN itself. Connected components are connected components, there is no ambiguity at this point.

You could write your own rules to extract the X most significant costs from an OPTICS plot though. OPTICS is the more variable formulation of DBSCAN.